# How do I manage the backup process for a VPS?

Tags: windows, backup, vps, windows-server-2016, database-backup

I have a platform that I would like to offer for my client. It is a SaaS platform in which I need to host it. It sounds like VPS is one way to go but 
I never owned/managed a VPS so not sure how to manage it.

I am looking at a Windows VPS from (https://www.interserver.net/vps/windows-vps.html). However, I am not sure how to manage the backup process in case something went wrong.

How can I manage the backup process on windows based VPS? Do I backup databases only or both databases and the server itself?

Comment: That's somewhat up to you. Backup what you can't replace (or what would be time consuming to replace). If users upload important images to the server, you should probably back those up. If you hand-write your server configs instead of using a configuration management system, back those up to. etc.

Comment: @ceejayoz good point, I will have images to back up along with the databases. How can I generate auto backup on the VPS?

Comment: There are a wide variety of available Windows server backup systems available, ranging quite a bit in price and complexity. Your host may also offer something.

Comment: Unfortunately they don’t. It is something I have to worry about. Is there any free backup solution that I could use?